# tableviews cells are changing after scrolling down

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am making a form within a grouped tableview. In this form I have UIswitches and textfields. But after scrolling down, the cells styles are changing.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"GenericCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
    }
        NSString *text = nil;

    if(indexPath.section == CREDENTIALS_SECTION){
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            NSLog(@"tot hier login");
            UITextField *login = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            login.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            login.placeholder = @"example@gmail.com";
            login.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
            login.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            login.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            login.tag = 0;
            login.delegate = self;

            [login setEnabled: YES];

            [cell addSubview:login];
        }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            NSLog(@"tot hier pass");
            UITextField *pass = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            pass.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            pass.placeholder = @"Required";
            pass.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            pass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            pass.secureTextEntry = YES;

            pass.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            pass.tag = 0;
            pass.delegate = self;
            [cell addSubview:pass];
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 0) { // Email
            text = @"Email";
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
            text = @"Password";
        }
    }else  if(indexPath.section == METHODS_SECTION){
        UISwitch *toggleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 30)];
        toggleSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
        [toggleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell addSubview:toggleSwitch];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) { // Web
            text = @"Web applicatie";
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1) { //Mobile
            text = @"Mobiele applicatie";
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 2) { //Mail
            text = @"E-mail";
        }


    }else  if(indexPath.section == PHONE_SECTION){
        UITextField *phoneText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 185, 30)];
        phoneText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        phoneText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
        phoneText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        phoneText.delegate = self;
        phoneText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        phoneText.text = _person.phone;
        [cell addSubview:phoneText];


    }else  if(indexPath.section == REMARK_SECTION){
        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 260)];
        textView.text = _person.remark;
        textView.delegate = self;
        textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
        textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell addSubview:textView];
        text = @"";


    }else  if(indexPath.section == BUTTON_SECTION){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        text = @"test";

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    return cell;
}
```

After some searching I found that more people are having this problem. And that the problem lays in this piece of code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"GenericCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
    }
        NSString *text = nil;
```

But I don't find a solution for it.
Hope anybody can help!

Kind regards!

**Clarification**

Oké so here you see a screenshot of my form.  below I have a red cell (save button) when I scroll down other cells are getting a red background. And some cells, text property's are changing.
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with *But after scrolling down, the cells styles are changing.*? Thanks.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What exactly changes in an unexpected way. What do you expect and what happens instead of that?

Comment: I've edited my question with a screenshot

Comment: Can you try my answer below which may help you???

Comment: And you are right Stef Geelen. The problem is in the part of reusing cell by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. This problem will solve if you remove all subViews from that cell before reusing..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the meantime I understood your problem. Please see my answer. It provides a number of alternative solutions. However, it is keen that you try understanding the concept of re-using of table cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not gong to work. Aparently you did not yet fully understand how the re-use mechanism works.

What do you do?
First you fetch a cell to be re-used. If you get one -fine so far but the problem comes later. If you don't get one then you create a new one.

When you have created a new one, which is the case at start before the user begins scrolling, then you add some UIItems depending on section and row. I will explain why this is not actually a smart thing to do.

Then the user scrolls. Cells will dissappear from screen and then made available for re-use. Then you will fetch the cells for re-use. But it may well happen that those cells already have additional UI-Items on them because you have used them before in that way. In the following process you will add new UI Items regardless whether there are already additional UI-Items on that very cell.

What can you do:

1. Create your own custom table cell subclasses. One subclass for each set of additional ui items that you may need. That is probably the neatest way of doing it. For each subclass use a different re-use identifier (!!!)
   This is what I would recommend!
   However, there are alternatives:
2. You could still live with your concept but invent an individual type of re-use identfier for each type of cell that has some type of additional ui item on it. If so, then make sure that these UI items are only created and added as sub-views in the `if (cell == nil)` branch of your code. Only create them once and then re-use them. Cell reuse-IDs could be "email-display", "email-input" , "password-display", "password-input", "switch", ...
3. A variance of the solution above would be, to calculate row and section
   into the reuse-identifier. Such as "cell-id-0.2" for section 0 and
   row 2 - or so. But still you will have to make sure that you really
   re-use the additional UI views and do not re-create them every time
   when the cell is filled with data. Plus, the layout in your first section varies depending on whether you want to input password and e-mail or just display them. You will still have to deal with those variations.
4. If cell == nil - meaning if a cell is re-used - then first clean it from every UI item that you may have added before. You can do that by tagging your UIViews with - let's say 99 - (anything different from 0 should do) upon creation and when reusing enumerate over all subviews and remove those, which have the tag 99. Despite that you can stick with the code that you have already made.

Comment: First of all thank you for you're detailed answer. But what solution do you recommend? What is the best practice way to do it?

Comment: Solution no 4 is the easiest for you because then you do not have to change mutch of your code. Solution no 1 is recommended. It does come with the most workload for a start but that will pay off by providing you with most maintainalbe and re-usable code. It is the most work for now but the least work for the future.

Comment: So if I understand correctly for every section create a new UICustomTableViewCell?

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thank you very much for explaining this concept. I often solved this problem by removing all subviews from the cell when reusing. +1 for sharing this... :)

Comment: @StefGeelen, in your case it comes close to having one unique ID for each cell because you are using so many different layouts. (Unless you go for solution no. 4. One ID for all would do in that case.) However, the three switches in the section "Methodes" would work perfectly well with one common ID for all three of them.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GenericCell"] ;
    //some more code
    return cell;
}
```

This would remove the reusability from the tableview, but since it's a limited settings view, it can be ok. I would still advice taking 1 or 2 from Hermann Klecker's solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you also need to persist UIControl state then use

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GenericCell%d",indexPath.row];
```

It will always return your unique table row and you can use it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all subviews from cell before reusing it. Try the code :

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
}
else
{
   [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

Comment: It would work for you. But it would really eliminate ALL subviews including the standart text label. But you do use the standard text lable at least in some cases. So if you want to apply this solutio then you would have to add a regular text lable for those cases where you need it.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Oké, where should I put the code above ? and should I step off the thing by using cell.textlabel.text = text ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all subviews before adding the subviews on cell.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier]autorelease];
}
else 
{
    //To remove the subview of cell.
    for (UIView *vwSubviews in [cell.contentView subviews])
    {
            [vwSubviews removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

It may solves your problem.

Comment: This corresponds with my suggestion no. 4. Just make sure that you remove only what you may have added before. You can use the tag to identify those subviews.

Comment: Actually here only subviews of contentview are removed so no need of giving tag & it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have some bad code here.

In the mehthod

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Unless it is not in `if (cell == nil)`, you should NOT initialize and use any

```
-(void)addSubview:(UIView*)view
```

Why?

The cells are views which are reused from tableview. So If you add some subview, next time while reusing the cell, it will be added more subviews on it. Simply they are overlapped and may cause MEMORY LEAK.

Do not forget that cells are reusable. So;

if I have the  following code unless I do not set text somewhere else. It is expected to all cells has the text in their text labels "this is a text". Because they are reusable.

```
if (someChangingBool) {
   cell.textLabel.text = @"this is a text"; 
}
```

So I need to have an else for that if which sets the text something else.

For [more Information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).