# UIButton subview in UITableViewCell doesn't hide as expected

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My recent frustration is a `UIButton` subview in each `UITableViewCell` of my `UITableView` which I want to `setHidden:` according to a specific clause for each `indexPath`. My code is pretty much the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [self initCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    [self updateCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

and the init and update methods are the following:

```
- (void)initCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    UIButton *btnMy = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnMy.tag = kButtonMyTag;
    [btnMy setFrame:CGRectMake(170, 45, 100, 30)];
    [btnMy setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnMy.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [btnMy setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnMy.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:14];
    [btnMy addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMyPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:btnMy];

    UIImageView *imgViewAccessory = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_accessory"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imgViewAccessory;
    [imgViewAccessory release];
}

- (void)updateCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIButton *btnMy = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:kButtonMyTag];

    MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(object.meetsCondition) 
    {
        btnMy.hidden = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        btnMy.hidden = YES;
    }
    ...
}
```

The frustrating result is that when scrolling the button shows and hides randomly and not as expected according the if clause in the updateCell method.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add button to cell.contentView instead of cell..

Comment: That didn't help either. Thanx though.

Comment: Check the answer in this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877137/tableviews-cells-are-changing-after-scrolling-down/

Comment: Why dont you make a cutom cell?

Comment: Worked fine with custom cell implementation. All I wanted was to avoid it but as soon as it works I am ok with it.
Thank you all again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make custom cell and depending upon the condition show and hide the button

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *nib;
    static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *theCell = [self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if([theCell.contentView subviews]){
        for(UIView *view in [theCell.contentView subviews]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if(theCell== nil)
    {
        nib  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Your custom cell name" owner:self options:nil]; 
        theCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        theCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[theCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
if(yourcondition)
//hide button
else
//show button
}
```

This will do

Comment: I was trying to avoid the custom UITableViewCell implementation but this solved my issue. Thanx amar!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `CellForRowAtIndexPath` Also.

```
 MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(object.meetsCondition) {
        btnMy.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        btnMy.hidden = YES;
    }
```

Comment: Better take `CustomtableCell`  here is a tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/